# Related Field got invalid lookup: icontains in admin.py

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-queryset

I know this problem have been posted before with its respective solution, but I do not know what is the problem in this specific case, Im trying to add a searching bar in the admin page of a specific class called "Dish" here is the context:

**Error in browser**

```
FieldError at /admin/menu/dish/
Related Field got invalid lookup: icontains
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://www.lupita.restaurant/admin/menu/dish/?q=naranja
Django Version: 4.0.6
Exception Type: FieldError
Exception Value:    
Related Field got invalid lookup: icontains
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py, line 1262, in build_lookup
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
Python Version: 3.10.5
Python Path:    
['/home/juanfrax/lupita',
 '/var/www',
 '.',
 '',
 '/var/www',
 '/usr/local/lib/python310.zip',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.10',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload',
 '/home/juanfrax/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 10 Feb 2023 03:38:57 +0000
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py, line 55, in inner
                response = get_response(request) …
Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py, line 197, in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) …
Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py, line 683, in wrapper
                return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs) …
Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py, line 133, in _wrapped_view
                    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) …
Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py, line 62, in _wrapped_view_func
        response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) …
Local vars
```

**models.py:
**

```
class Dish(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    descripcion = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    categoria = models.ForeignKey('Categoria', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='dishes_img/', blank=True, null=True)
    tags = TaggableManager(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'dish'
        verbose_name_plural = 'dishes'


class Category(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ' category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug and self.category_name:
            self.slug = slugify(self.category_name)
        super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('menu:view_menu_slug_en', args=[self.slug])


class Categoria(models.Model):
    nombre_categoria = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre_categoria

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug and self.nombre_categoria:
            self.slug = slugify(self.nombre_categoria)
        super(Categoria, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('menu:view_menu_slug_es', args=[self.slug])
```

**admin.py
**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.admin import AdminSite

from .models import Dish, Categoria


# Register your models here.


class MealsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):  # instead of ModelAdmin
    list_display = ['nombre', 'descripcion', 'categoria', 'price']
    search_fields = ['nombre', 'descripcion']
    list_filter = ['categoria']


admin.site.register(Dish, MealsAdmin)
admin.site.register(Categoria)
AdminSite.enable_nav_sidebar = False
```

I want the results of the query , this is pretty obvious, thanks ahead for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

You should also add `name` field in `search_fields` attribute in `MealsAdmin` in admin.py so:

```py
class MealsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):  # instead of ModelAdmin
    list_display = ['nombre', 'descripcion', 'categoria', 'price']
    search_fields = ['nombre', 'descripcion', 'name']
    list_filter = ['categoria']
```

This will allow you to search for a dish by its name or description, regardless of case.

Comment: It did not work either. The class Dish has names in Spanish and English

Comment: @JFAA can you share your those views which realates to this model, I think problem is with something else.

Comment: search_fields = use my  views.py? I though is using the function from ModelAdmin?